# Advertisement(looking like contact form) form error in php

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I want to prepare an advertisement form in php...
i am preparing some code like this. but finally it say's errors in page. how to rectify my code with this requirements.

```
<form action="advertisement-form.php" class="comment-form row-fluid" data-validate="parsley">

                            <p>
                                <label for="name" class="span2">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="span10" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="name" required >
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="email" class="span2">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="span10" placeholder="Your E-mail" id="email" name="email" required >
                            </p>

                                <p>
                                <label for="name" class="span2">Your Ad Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="span10" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" name="name" required >
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Target URL</label>
                                <input type="text" name="site" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Banner URL</label>
                                <input type="text" name="site" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="site" class="span2">Payment Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="site" class="span10" data-type="url" required>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <label for="mess" class="span2">Message</label>
                                <textarea name="mess" class="span10" data-trigger="keyup" data-rangelength="[20,1000]"></textarea>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button button-load large-button offset2 span4">
                            </p>
                        </form>
```

and my advertisement-form.php is looking like this

```
<?php 
//////////////////////////
//Specify default values//
//////////////////////////

//Your E-mail
$your_email = 'info@divisdesigns.com';

 //Default Subject if 'subject' field not specified
$default_subject = 'From My Contact Form';

//Message if 'name' field not specified
$name_not_specified = 'Please type a valid name';

//Message if 'message' field not specified
$message_not_specified = 'Please type a vaild message';

//Message if e-mail sent successfully
$email_was_sent = 'Thanks, your message successfully sent';

//Message if e-mail not sent (server not configured)
$server_not_configured = 'Sorry, mail server not configured';


///////////////////////////
//Contact Form Processing//
///////////////////////////
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['name'])) {
if(!empty($_POST['name']))
    $sender_name  = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])));

if(!empty($_POST['message']))
    $message      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['message'])));

if(!empty($_POST['email']))
    $sender_email = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));

if(!empty($_POST['subject']))
    $subject      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['subject'])));


//Message if no sender name was specified
if(empty($sender_name)) {
    $errors[] = $name_not_specified;
}

//Message if no message was specified
if(empty($message)) {
    $errors[] = $message_not_specified;
}

$from = (!empty($sender_email)) ? 'From: '.$sender_email : '';

$subject = (!empty($subject)) ? $subject : $default_subject;

$message = (!empty($message)) ? wordwrap($message, 70) : '';

//sending message if no errors
if(empty($errors)) {
    if (mail($your_email, $subject, $message, $from)) {
        echo $email_was_sent;
    } else {
        $errors[] = $server_not_configured;
        echo implode('<br>', $errors );
    }
} else {
    echo implode('<br>', $errors );
}
}
?>
```

and finally this code displays error...
can you solve for me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: like thisWe are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.

Please go back and fix these errors.

Comment: So you want to then display the errors to the user? Not there are errors in your code and it doesn't work?

Comment: The errors you say in your comment are not visible in your code. Can you post all relative code?

Answer (score 0):

add `method="POST"` inside your `<form>` tag
`<form method="POST" action="">`

Comment: @divis         first of all you are not getting form data to `advertisement-form.php` page.You missed `method="POST"`,add this and try.